# SSRS report with same column grouping

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Is it possible? Im trying to create rdl and want to showcase my report like this.

```
---------------------------------------
Ship #  Loc Ship
---------------------------------------     
ABC     

630-4144    0   ABC
630-4144    0   ABC
```

Comment: why'd you need the duplicates? perhaps you could do that!

Comment: it is clients legacy report so we have to create like that... otherwise it seems very wired in report. :|

Comment: Have you looked at a List control? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239330.aspx

Comment: Your question is pretty meaningless. Yes it is possible.